# EM algorithm, read and save XML file

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to save my classifier, and then when I am trying to read it back, it throws segmentation error. I tried to figure it out, and I think it is a bug with opencv.

Here is my code:

```
    bool result = model.train(samples,Mat(),ps,&lables);    
    printf("Train Result %d\n",result);        
    CvFileStorage *fs;
    fs =  cvOpenFileStorage("skin_new.xml",NULL, CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
    model.write_params(fs);
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fs );
    CvFileStorage *fs1;
    //Reading back XML file
    fs1 =  cvOpenFileStorage("skin_new.xml",NULL , CV_STORAGE_READ);
    classifier.read_params(fs1,NULL);
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fs1 );
    printf("XML reading done\n");
    //the two dominating colors
    Mat means = model.getMeans();//This step leads to segmentation error
```

I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1.

Comment: You should post more of your code, and/or check if any of the preceding steps fail at runtime (i.e. make sure your objects are properly initialized, your file opens successfully, etc). Also, why are you mixing the C and C++ OpenCV APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are developing in Linux OS. So I think you don't have the access permission to the skin_new.xml file.

You can use

```
chmod 777 skin_new.xml
```

But it's temporary. I'm facing the same problem as well.